# What happened to section marks in podcasts?

Tags: podcasts

When I started listening to podcasts over 4 years ago, I noticed that a number of them included "section marks" (aka chapter marks) in the audio timeline which allowed you to jump from section to section in a single click.  The podcast producer would use these sections to break up the podcast into logical chunks.

At the time, I didn't believe this functionality was specific to a certain type of device and/or file format and/or producer.

I don't see these anywhere now.  Would like to have them back as they were a useful feature.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It looks like](http://www.makezine.com/extras/43.html) this is only available if the podcast is encoded as AAC, which would make life difficult for many potential listeners.

(The relatively few) Podcasters bothering to produce enhanced podcasts therefore end up producing a plain mp3 version anyway, so when subscribing, make sure you get the right feed

Comment: hi Neil good find on the Makezine article.

Your comment about relatively few bothering to make enhanced podcasts definitely seems true, as I think half of my podcasts come encoded as AAC and still don't have this info encoded.  

Perhaps the extra production effort didn't result in greater listenership.